# Adding prepayment to a Sales Order

Tags: erp, acumatica

I have a requirement to add pre-payment to a sales order. Accounting has setup the required classes and payment methods in Acumatica. I am able to do this through the GUI, but when I try to enter the payment information on the sales order using the Web Service, I get an error response back. The error response is: PX.Data.PXException: Error #14: Inserting  'SOAdjust' record raised one or more errors. Please review. Error: 'Reference Nbr.' may not be empty.

`   SO301000Content SO301000 = context.SO301000GetSchema();
            context.SO301000Clear();

```
        List<Command> cmds = new List<Command>();
        cmds.AddRange(new Command[]{

            new Value {Value = "C3", LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderType},
            new Value { Value = orderNbr, LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderNbr, Commit = true},

            SO301000.Payments.ServiceCommands.NewRow,

            new Value { Value = "Prepayment", LinkedCommand = SO301000.Payments.DocType},
            new Value { Value = paymentNbr, LinkedCommand = SO301000.Payments.ReferenceNbr, Commit = true },
           // new Value { Value = "3.00" , LinkedCommand = SO301000.Payments.AppliedToOrder, Commit = true},

            SO301000.Actions.Save,
            SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderNbr
        });

        string orderNumber = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            var SO301000ContentReturned = context.SO301000Submit(cmds.ToArray());
            orderNumber = SO301000ContentReturned[0].OrderSummary.OrderNbr.Value;
            Console.WriteLine(orderNumber);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            orderNumber = exception.Message;
            Console.WriteLine(exception);
        }


        return orderNumber;`
```

Any suggestions? I have tried using the AR302000 screen as well to apply the payment to the order from the payment screen and received the same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known limitation in grids that are driven by two key fields (in this case: DocType+ReferenceNbr). In this scenario, only the 2nd key should have Commit=true set, so you need to set Commit=false on the DocType field. But instead of doing it from the Value object, you need to do it  on the schema content object.

The other Commit=true and the NewRow command are unnecessary. I've edited your original code below, this is how it should look:

```
    SO301000.Payments.DocType.Commit = false; //This is the line that I added
    List<Command> cmds = new List<Command>();
    cmds.AddRange(new Command[]{
        new Value {Value = "C3", LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderType},
        new Value { Value = orderNbr, LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderNbr},

        new Value { Value = "Prepayment", LinkedCommand = SO301000.Payments.DocType},
        new Value { Value = paymentNbr, LinkedCommand = SO301000.Payments.ReferenceNbr},
        //new Value { Value = "3.00" , LinkedCommand = SO301000.Payments.AppliedToOrder},

        SO301000.Actions.Save,
        SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderNbr
    });

    string orderNumber = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        var SO301000ContentReturned = context.SO301000Submit(cmds.ToArray());
        orderNumber = SO301000ContentReturned[0].OrderSummary.OrderNbr.Value;
        Console.WriteLine(orderNumber);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        orderNumber = exception.Message;
        Console.WriteLine(exception);
    }


    return orderNumber;
```

Comment: Note - I do think the Commit flag should be set automatically; i'm going to check with the engineering team why it wasn't done in this case...

Comment: Did you remove Commit = True from all other lines? Can you e-mail a sample console app that points to your dev site at gmichaud@acumatica.com for me to look at?